# Missing Test Settings template in VS2010 Ultimate

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2010

I'm attempting to add a Test Settings file to my Unit Tests project in VS2010.  All websites seem to simply say "Go to Add New Item > Installed Templates > Test Settings".  However, I don't have Test Settings as an option in my Installed Templates (nor does searching for them online turn up any results).

Can someone point me in the right direction for what I need to do?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Unless they changed this dramatically since VS2k8, you'll see that when you create a new test project, you'll get a new "solution folder" in your solution called "Solution Items" with a `.testRunConfiguration` file in it which contains the settings.

If not, then you can create the "solution folder" yourself.  Right-mouse click on your solution and select Add -> New Solution Folder.  Right-mouse click on the folder and select Add -> New Item.  Select "Test Run Configuration" under "Categories".  *If you click on the project, you will not see these choices.*

If that doesn't still work in VS2k10, I'll be interested in knowing.

**Response to JustLoren's Comment**  I did a quick Google search and found this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vststest/thread/8ef10a3a-d4d5-4931-9054-df1d81ee4842..

Apparently, they did change the file extension from .testrunconfig to .testsettings in VS2k10.  I believe that the key to solving your problem is likely to properly create the `Solution Items` solution folder and add your configuration file there.

Comment: Through that I was able to create a .testsettings file like most tutorials reference.  I even dragged it down into the UnitTests project.  However the menu option "Test > Edit Test Settings" still shows "No Active Settings".  Thoughts?

Comment: Indeed, putting the testsettings file into `Solution Items` instead of what I had previously named the folder as made all of the difference.  Thanks!

Comment: Cool.  I'm glad I could help.  When I create the first test project in a solution in VS2k8, it automatically creates `Solution Items` and puts a default test configuration file in `Solution Items`.  I'll be watching out for this odd behavior when we upgrade to VS2k10.

Answer (score 2):

For Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise, I had a really hard time figuring out how to create this file. I don't see the option in the Menu and creating a "Solution" or "Solution Items" folder did not get me any closer to the solution.

What I did was create a XML file and named it "Default.testsettings". VS will then complain:

> The Test Settings file XXXX does not have the expected format: Root
>   element is missing.

Then right click the new file and Select "Open With...", Then in the resulting window select "Source Code (Text) Editor" then hit OK.

[image]

An empty XML file should open, paste the following code into the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<TestSettings name="TestSettings1" 
    id="c75a9e88-b995-43e0-964b-ff82703d6650" 
    xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010">
</TestSettings>
```

Then save and exit the file, double click the "Default.testsettings" to open it in the default "Test Settings Editor". You should now be able to edit the file normally.